# how to call to the anonymous array in the objects property jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, properties

I use a constructor to create an object

```
function player(name,state,score,marker,combination) {
    this.name = name;
    this.state = state;
    this.score = score;
    this.marker = marker;
    this.combination = combination;
}
```

Where property "combination" should be an array. At the point of creating of an PLAYER object instance, I set the array this way:

```
players[players.length] = new player(name,false,0,'marker',[]);
```

Then I dynamically set the values to the array inside the "combination" property, but I don't know how to find the length of the current array

```
players[i].combination[ANONYMOUS ARRAY.length] = some value;
```

I see that I'm missing some crucial knowledge here. Could please someone help me out here? Suggest the proper manner of either setting an array inside the object's property / treating such an array???

Comment: `players[i].combination[players[i].combination.length] = some value;` or better `players[i].combination.push(some value);`

Comment: Thanks man, I used the push() option. This works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be `players[i].combination.length`, because `players[i].combination` is the reference to the array:

```
players[i].combination[players[i].combination.length] = some_value;
```

Or of course:

```
players[i].combination.push(some_value);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear answer with the explanation! I have used push() option indeed and this works just fine!

Answer (score 2):

I'd use push() instead of putting an index and guessing the length, so instead of:

`players[players.length] = new player(name,false,0,'marker',[]);`
do
`players.push(new player(name,false,0,'marker',[]);`

Instead of 
`players[i].combination[ANONYMOUS ARRAY.length] = some value;`
I guess you know the value of 'i', do `players[i].combination.push(some_value)`

or if you don't know i then just create the combination array and pass it when creating players

Comment: Hee, thank's a lot! I have voted your answer up, I couldn't choose 2 correct answers :-) In this case you were right - I don't have really to know the length of an array, I can just push(). But in some cases I gues it could be needed - to know the length of the array.